# How to update multiple entries of a certain column of a Pandas dataframe in certain order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

Let’s say I have the following Pandas dataframe, where the `'key'` column only contains unique strings:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'key':['b','d','c','a','e','f'], 'value': [0,0,0,0,0,0]})
df

  key value
0   b     0
1   d     0
2   c     0
3   a     0
4   e     0
5   f     0
```

Now I have a list of unique keys and a list of corresponding values:

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to update the `'value'` column in the same order of the lists, so that each row has matched `'key'` and `'value'` (`a` to `1`, `'b'` to `2`, `'c'` to `3`, `'d'` to `4`). I am using the following code, but the dataframe seems to update values from top to bottom, which I don't quite understand

```
df.loc[df['key'].isin(keys),'value'] = values
df

  key value
0   b     1
1   d     2
2   c     3
3   a     4
4   e     0
5   f     0
```

To be clear, I am expecting to get

```
  key value
0   b     2
1   d     4
2   c     3
3   a     1
4   e     0
5   f     0
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
dd = dict(zip(keys, values))
df['value'] = df['key'].map(dd).fillna(df['value'])
```

Comment: Although it works, I am getting `SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: @ShaunHan that’s a different issue. There are a lot of topics about this on SO already. The gist is that your `df` might be a slice of a bigger dataframe and you want to make a copy with `df=df.copy()` before you modify it.

Answer (score 1):

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# form a dictionary with keys and values list
d=dict(zip(keys, values))

# update the value where mapping exists using LOC and MAP 
df.loc[df['key'].map(d).notna(), 'value'] =df['key'].map(d)
df
```

```
    key     value
0     b     2
1     d     4
2     c     3
3     a     1
4     e     0
5     f     0
```

Comment: This only works if the original dataframe contains only 0 at other keys that are not included in the list (e.g. ``'e'`` and ``'f'``). I need a solution that do not update other entries. I use 0 just as an example.

Comment: updated the solution.

Comment: hope it work now

Answer (score 1):

with a temporary dataframe:

```
temp_df = df.set_index('key')
temp_df.loc[keys] = np.array(values).reshape(-1, 1)
df = temp_df.reset_index()
```